# GraphQL API (Astra DB) - the list of existing tables and fields

Tags: database, cassandra, graphql, datastax-astra, stargate-oss

What is the query syntax for getting the list of all previously created tables?
And how can I then view selected table fields?

Answer (score 2):

Get a description of the tables in your "sample_keyspace":

```
query GetTables {
  keyspace(name: "sample_keyspace") {
    name
    tables {
      name
      columns {
        name
        kind
        type {
          basic
          info {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```